# OOmisc accept.reject

Tags: r, rstudio

I would like to use accept.reject from OOmisc library but it is not available after installed by RStudio:

```
> install.packages("OOmisc")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.4/OOmisc_1.2.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 34906 bytes (34 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 34 KB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/3g/p1x630wx3vv2sympgy37pw000000gn/T//RtmpWCEL6G/downloaded_packages
```

I found this library here:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/OOmisc/versions/1.2/topics/accept.reject

```
> accept.reject(density,0,10,1000)
Error in accept.reject(density, 0, 10, 1000) : 
  could not find function "accept.reject"
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Did you remember to load the package? `library(OOmisc)`

Comment: It is as @Dason said, you may want to check if you have loaded the library. Additionally, provide a good, repeatable script so that we can run your exact case.

Comment: I did not know that I have to load it after install. Thanks!